# Removing a Node in a BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble getting my `remove300` and `removeNode300` function working correctly when I remove the root of the tree. (In my case 8). Everything works right(compiling wise), but when I call me `inView` function, which displays the numbers in the binary tree in ascending order, it takes that `8` out and just puts the highest number in 8's place.

For example: 
I insert these numbers in this order, `8,4,12,2,6,10,14,20` and call me remove function to remove 8. I get this output  `2,4,5,20,10,12,14`. I want it to be `2,4,6,10,12,14,20`.

If I can get some help on this on why this process isn't working please let me know. Also let me know if I have to add anything to this post inorder to help you.

Struct definition:

```
typedef float Element300;
struct TreeNode300;
typedef TreeNode300 * TreePtr300;
struct TreeNode300
{
    Element300 element;
    TreePtr300 left;
    TreePtr300 right;
};
```

Remove Function:

```
void BST300::remove300(const Element300 element, TreePtr300 & root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Error: Remove Failed!" << endl;
    }
    else if(element == root->element )
    {
        removeNode300(root);
    }
    else if(element < root->element)
    {
        remove300(element, root->left);
    }
    else
    {
        remove300(element, root->right);
    }
    return;
}
```

Remove Node function:

```
void BST300::removeNode300(TreePtr300 & root)
{
    TreePtr300 tempPointer = NULL;

    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
    else if(root->right == NULL)
    {
        tempPointer = root;
        root = root->left;
        tempPointer->left = NULL;
        delete tempPointer;
    }
    else if(root->left == NULL)
    {
        tempPointer = root;
        root = root->right;
        tempPointer->right = NULL;
        delete tempPointer;
    }
    else
    {
        findMaxNode300(root->right, tempPointer);
        root->element = tempPointer->element;
        delete tempPointer;
    }
    tempPointer = NULL;
    return;
}
```

find Maximum value function:

```
void BST300::findMaxNode300(TreePtr300 & root, TreePtr300 & tempPointer)
{
    if(root->right == NULL)
    {
        tempPointer = root;
        root = root->left;
        tempPointer->left = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        findMaxNode300(root->right, tempPointer);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Since you are choosing an element to replace the root from the right, it would need to be the min from the right, and not the max.

Comment: I need the max to be there. If the root gets remove I have to have the root be the maximum number in the BST.

Comment: No, any node value must be bigger than any value in left sub-tree and less than any in right. You do like this in insert function.

Comment: If the number is smaller than the root of the tree, it goes left, other wise its right (ignoring dupes). @MichaelNastenko

Comment: Yes, and it makes root bigger than any value in left subtree and smaller than any value in right subtree. Exactly as I said before.